# Recognising method was called by instance

Tags: python, instance, python-decorators

I am currently trying to make some decorators helping users of my software to create code which will inform them about some issues.

Doing classes, I sometimes work with methods which I would like to use only within the class, but not to be called in instance. I know this can be worked out with underscores and dunders, but I don't want to make user's experience a hell, just a little nudge with warning that they used it in scope which is not intended to have such method used.

Let me explain on code block:

```py
class Example:

   def __init__(self):
       self.sth = 0

   def callableMethod(self, is_true):
       if is_true: 
          self.otherMethod()
       print (self.sth)

   @NoInstanceMethod
   def otherMethod(self):
       self.sth = 1
```

Basically what I would like to achieve is that user can create object and use both methods, but when they try to use `otherMethod` on instance, like that:

```py
i = Example()
i.otherMethod()
```

I would be able to recognise it and do something to warn the user (through print or logging message, it doesn't matter).
Is there a way to recognise that the method is used on instance in such a way, but not raise the warning on `callableMethod` (as it is correctly used scope)?

Comment: That's what `_otherMethod` means. If they insist on calling a method that's not part of the public interface, that's not your problem. Don't try to make it your problem.

Comment: That said, `i.__otherMethod()` will raise an exception unless it occurs in the definition of one of `Example's` other methods. I'm really not sure why you think you need an alternative.

Comment: I'm asking for general knowledge, as "instance call recognition" can be useful for other purposes than my initial (feedback) one. And my purpose is because I don't want to prohibit user accessing the method, but have reminder of it in logs, as my software tries to achieve log <> user workflow. For the context, I'm also such user and I sometimes test those methods use outside of scope - but with underscores it returns AttributeError, as expected.

Comment: Short of using `inspect` to examine the source code to see the context in which `i.otherMethod()` is called, the information you want isn't available.